# Using Precise Insubstantial linked to Growth to trap people in a Walking Prison?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Trying to figure out if the following is interpretation is RAW, disregarding rule 0 for clarity.

**The intended mechanic** is for a boss monster to use Growth (probably of some kind of inorganic/constructed body character or projections like Extra Limbs), using Insubstantial 1-2 (Precise), where you keep your original form on the inside surrounded by the Insubstantial material, trapping you and someone else within it by keeping the outer layer of your Growth substantial, using Precise to Teleport around as you make different parts of yourself Substantial within the body to keep hitting them and possibly some form of Contagious Fire Attacks to keep in contact with them.

**The intended descriptor** for this in particular was to make a kind of "forced duel" moment where those outside can't get in and those you trap can't get out until you are incapacitated or turn it off willingly. I was thinking of also invoking some kind of Contagious Damage/Affliction effect for those within it, probably with Triggered: On contact or something similar to also spread it to those that try to attack the outer layer in an attempt to get in.

Most noteworthy things are that while you are effectively using a Trapping Effect from Create or Transform, its with the benefits of making the Trap Movable, with Feedback since you still take damage, with constant contact due to Insubstantial Material still counting, and with the stat benefits gained from Growth, and if you leave small gaps through Precise you can potentially trap even more people.

I suspect you might need Morph and some special Senses to make sure the inner body is still a effective body but I'm not sure if you can't just solve that with the descriptors of how Growth works (maybe more Attack on Titan where its not actually your real body).

Not sure how about how RAW this and the means of making it not horrifying is, particularly in that I'm not sure if you're allowed to make your Growth 'projected' or constructed if you're looking for a less gruesome way of using this that is more object/suit based, though perhaps just being construct-like or plant-like yourself may be reasonable, expanding the influence of your mechanism (like Groot in Guardians of the Galaxy). Feels cool to me though I am concerned about trapping someone and then having Regeneration or Immunity so that no amount of damage they can feasibly deal would be enough to actually can allow them to escape.